# How were the Russians going to invade the world?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**1984 - Location: classified**

"Commander, we've received a message from a deep cover asset in Russia".

"Well decode it then! What does it say?"

"It's the enigma asset boss. He doesn't trust ciphers, never uses them. But he's sent us this. Apparently it's the name of Russia's latest weapon, ready to invade the entire world!"

You are handed a sheet of paper, all it contains is a list of numbers:

```
43.653226 -79.383184
55.953252 -3.188267
35.689487 139.691706
41.902783 12.496366
33.729388 73.093146
59.329323 18.068581
```

Comment: This has far fewer steps than my last couple of puzzles, it's just a quick idea I came up with. Good luck :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The threat from Russia is:

> **Tetris**

It is encoded like so:

> The numbers are longitudes and latitudes of cities, given in decimal form instead of the usual degrees, minutes and seconds:
>
>  43.653226, −79.383184 — **T**oronto
>  55.953252, −3.188267 — **E**dinburgh
>  35.689487, 139.691706 — **T**okyo
>  41.902783, 12.496366 — **R**ome
>  33.729388, 73.093146 — **I**slamabad
>  59.329323, 18.068581 — **S**tockholm
>
>  The first letters of the cities spell out the answer: **TETRIS**.

Comment: I think I need to make the next one trickier, nicely done :)

Comment: Completely unimportant funfact: The Russian folk song "Korobeniki" was used for the iconic TETRIS music!

Comment: @TimB: No, it was good, a snack-sized puzzle with a nice idea. I got lucky and the first thing I tried gave a good result.